# Same document Id in a collection group but in different parents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is possible to have repeated document IDs in the same **collection group** but in different parents?

The question is specifically about collection groups.

Ex.

Collections:

- Collection `user`
- Collection group `whishlist` under collection called

Documents:

- Doc1 => `user/USER_ID_1/whishlist/DEFAULT_LIST`
- Doc2 => `user/USER_ID_2/whishlist/DEFAULT_LIST`

Comment: Yup, totally fine (and relatively common) to use the same document ID in multiple collections. I linked a question where this was asked before. Specifically on **collection groups**, this is why the `__NAME__`/`documentId()` field in collection group indexes contains the **path** to the document and not its ID - as it's the only way to ensure the `__NAME__` is *globally* unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation regarding the [document IDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections):

> The names of documents within a collection are unique. You can provide your own keys, such as user IDs, or you can let Cloud Firestore create random IDs for you automatically.

So the IDs of the documents in Firestore should be *unique within the same collection* but since you're asking about a collection group (different collections or sub-collections), then yes, you can have documents with the same IDs.

So remember, the path of the documents should be *unique*, not the document ID itself.

Comment: I supposed that collection groups were managed internally like collections and the document id was the unique identifier. I understand now that the path is the real unique identifier, and not only the document id alone. right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the path of the documents should be unique, not the document ID itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  You should be able to try this easily for yourself by creating such documents in the console.